# Ionic view not refreshing data from API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

We have an Ionic app which polls a node/express API.

When the app starts it fetches the JSON data correctly from the API. When we update the data and fetch it again from the Ionic app, we still see the old data from the time that the app was launched.

We've tried to clear both the Angular cache and the Ionic cache in a variety of ways, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Things we've tried are:

`$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`, `cache-view="false"` on the template, setting `cache: false` on the state, tried accessing the state via `$state.go($state.currentState, {}, {reload : true});`, `$ionicHistory.clearHistory();` and `$ionicHistory.clearHistory();`, `$route.reload` and `$window.location.reload`.

Controller:

```
function contactsController(Contacts, $stateParams) {

  var vm = this;
  var params = $stateParams.id;
  Contacts.getAllContacts.then(function success(response) {
    vm.data = response.data;
    vm.selectedContact = response.data[params];
  });
}
```

Factory

```
function contactsFactory($http, $stateParams) {
  return {
    getAllContacts: $http.get('https://api-call'),
    update: function(url) {
      $http.patch('https://api-call/update', [$stateParams.id, url]);
    },
  };
}
```

Express Back end

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  ref.once("value", function(snapshot){
    res.send(snapshot.val());
  });
});

app.patch('/update', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.body[0];
  ref.child(id).update({"imageURL": req.body[1]});
});
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try disable cache on both of routing and view ?

Comment: Yes we did, thanks. I've just updated the post to include everything we've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

- Modify your view like this

```html
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
```

Comment: Thanks, we've already tried that actually, I've just updated the post listing all the things we've already tried.

Comment: try this but this is not a solution , but it will refresh the page and apply the changes , Paste this function and call through ng-init="doRefresh()"  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    
  };

Comment: Thanks, we've just tried this, and also tried putting that function on an ng-click event too, it temporarily clears the data but then refreshes it with the old data again.

Comment: Just Comment your code and run this and have a try i hop it will work   Contacts.getAllContacts.then(function success(response) {



    $scope.getdata = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            //wrapped this within $apply
         vm.data = response.data;
    vm.selectedContact = response.data[params];
          });
        }, 2000);
      }
      
      $scope.getdata();
  



  });

Comment: Okay, we've tried that, unfortunately it's still giving us the same result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did u get any idea  ??

Comment: After further investigation it seems that our API call is only ever happening once no matter how many times it's called, then each subsequent time it's simply returning the same data that it retrieved the first and only time that it ran. We're digging in now to investigate the cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

Try `console.log(vm)` and verify that the updated data are obtained. If its only the view thats not being updated despite updated data being logged, I would try the following along with `cache-view="false"`.

```
$scope.apply(function (){
   // update your view here
   vm.data = response.data;
   vm.selectedContact = response.data[params];
});
```

Comment: `console.log`ging vm shows that the updated data is never obtained, vm always contains the data from the first time it fetches from the API after the app starts.

Comment: could you try using `service` instead of `factory` for your `contactsFactory`?

Comment: We've tried using a service instead of a factory, unfortunately it seems to produce exactly the same results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using Firebase's [**`once()`**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html) you have effectively removed all callbacks attached to `value` besides the first one:

> Listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then
>   stops listening

Try switching to [**`on()`**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html) instead.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
    res.send(snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

It may be that your issue is not related to caching at all...

Comment: It seems that our API call is only ever happening once as you say, no matter how many times we call it. However when using on() instead of once() the backend crashes when accessed. That may be indicative of a problem elsewhere causing the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I install Ionic 2 Open layers map on android device, i can see Open layers map successfully on the android screen. But when i close it and open the app again, i cant see the map. To solve this problem , what i do is: i uninstall the app, restart my device, then reinstall the app, after that i can see the map.
Please provide me a permanent fix.

Answer (score 0):

Placing this in app config worked for me with

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

`$ionicConfigProvider` dependency in config.